# Scripting and interactive terminal client in Python

Tags: python

I need to script/automate an interactive terminal client using Python. The client accepts three arguments and runs as follows:

```
>./myclient <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>
Welcome...
blah...
blah..
[user input]
some more blah... blah... for the input entered
blah.. 
blah..
[basically it accepts input and puts the output in the console until the user types 'quit']
```

Now I need to automate this in Python and the console output saved in a file.

Comment: i tried the Popen but couldn't manage to run the terminal client effectively. I also wasn't able to send more than one input using communicate(). When i used stdin=PIPE and then send the data using stdin.read the client was acting weird

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to use [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) (which is a pure-python version of the venerable expect).

```
import pexpect
proc = pexpect.spawn('./myclient <arg1> <arg2> <arg3>')
proc.logfile = the_logfile_you_want_to_use
proc.expect(['the string that tells you that myclient is waiting for input'])
proc.sendline('line you want to send to myclient')
proc.expect(['another line you want to wait for'])
proc.sendline('quit') # for myclient to quit
proc.expect([pexpect.EOF])
```

Something like this should be enough to solve your case. pexpect is capable of a lot more though, so read up on the documentation for more advanced use-cases.

Comment: Thanks. This worked like charm. But now i have another issue. I am sending two inputs to the client
    `proc.sendline('input1')
     time.sleep(60)
     proc.sendline('input2')`
but the issue is that it doesn't wait. It seems to send the input irrespective of the thread.sleep(60)..

Comment: It's usually better not to try to sleep before sending data, but instead looking for some kind of acknowledgment message from the other process.

Answer (score 7):

You could have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html.

**Example code:**

```
import cmd
import sys

class Prompt(cmd.Cmd):
    def __init__(self, stufflist=[]):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = '>>> '
        self.stufflist = stufflist
        print "Hello, I am your new commandline prompt! 'help' yourself!"

    def do_quit(self, arg):
        sys.exit(0)

    def do_print_stuff(self, arg):
        for s in self.stufflist:
            print s

p = Prompt(sys.argv[1:])
p.cmdloop()
```

**Example test:**

```
$ python cmdtest.py foo bar
Hello, I am your new commandline prompt! 'help' yourself!
>>> help

Undocumented commands:
======================
help  print_stuff  quit

>>> print_stuff
foo
bar
>>> quit
```

In order to save the output to a file, you can write what usually goes to stdout also to a file, using for example this class:

```
class Tee(object):
    def __init__(self, out1, out2):
        self.out1 = out1
        self.out2 = out2

    def write(self, s):
        self.out1.write(s)
        self.out2.write(s)

    def flush(self):
        self.out1.flush()
        self.out2.flush()
```

You can use it like this:

```
with open('cmdtest.out', 'w') as f:
    # write stdout to file and stdout
    t = Tee(f, sys.stdout)
    sys.stdout = t
```

A problem is that the commands read in via stdin do not appear in this output, but I believe that this can be easily solved.

Comment: Very bad by someone to minus-vote. Although it might not be the best solution to this question, it is a highly informative and usable answer, that shows other options to solve this (so, I voted up to zero again).

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke just because someone asks a question and accepts an answer, does not mean the other answers are incorrect. :) I also found your answer to be quite informative.

Comment: @SunSparc I think this was about a down-vote and not about not being accepted :-)